# find feedback from text file from a list of training_id

Tags: python

I've a list of training_id_list= ['235', '121']
and I also have a sample txt file where feedback is saved in format:

```
576---Great training---5.0---235   
577---Not bad ---5.0---235
feedbacck_id--feedback--rating--training_id
```

Now, if I want to print the feedback for each training and if each training_id has more than 5 reviews, it should only print 5. how do I do that. I've tried:

```
    for element in training_id_list: 
      each_element = element 
    with open(r'sample.txt') as sample_txt: 
      read_sample_txt = sample_txt.readlines() 
      for line in read_sample_txt:
        feedback_id, feedback, rating, training_id = line.split('---') 
        if each_element in line: 
          print(feedback) 
          # But this method returns nothin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
training_id_list = ['235','233','234'] #your list which contains ids
max_print = 5
for id in training_id_list :
    with open(r'abc.txt') as sample_txt: 
        read_sample_txt = sample_txt.readlines()
        read_sample_txt = read_sample_txt[:-1:]
        printed_review_count = 1 
        for line in read_sample_txt:
            [feedback_id, feedback, rating,id_text] = line.split('---') 
            if id in id_text and printed_review_count  <= max_print : #last entry is id
                print(feedback)
                printed_review_count += 1
```

##### Input (abc.txt)

```
576---Great training---5.0---235   
577---Not bad ---5.0---235
577---Not bad1 ---5.0---235
577---Not bad2 ---5.0---235
577---Not bad3 ---5.0---235
577---Not bad4 ---5.0---235
576---Great training---5.0---235   
577---Not bad ---5.0---235
feedbacck_id--feedback--rating--training_id
```

##### Output

```
Great training
Not bad 
Not bad1 
Not bad2 
Not bad3
```

You have to just parse the thing correctly.

Assuming the format is always like this:

```
576---Great training---5.0---235   
577---Not bad ---5.0---235
feedbacck_id--feedback--rating--training_id
```

Note: If the input file contains the last line with `feedbacck_id--feedback--rating--training_id`  , you can ignore it.

Comment: What if I don't know the training_id '235'? I've extracted training_id as a list from JSON nested data

Comment: @Tech.: Doesn't matter..if you have a list of `ids` you can write it exactly like this `for element in training_id_list: ... `

Comment: @ user2736738 Thank you. If the id has more than 5 reviews, I wanna print only 5. How can I add it to your code

Comment: @Tech Check the code.

Comment: @ser2736738 I just tried running the code but returns nothin too

Comment: @Tech If your input is exactly this `576---Great training---5.0;;;235   
577---Not bad ---5.0;;;235` then it won't. The last line is not part of the input I assumed. Is it part of input?

Comment: @Tech Why did you edit the question after being answered? Do you expect me to answer your question taking my whole time?

Comment: here, 235 is an element that was extracted from nested JSON. for example, an instructor has id 121 and based on it, I've extracted all the training_id in a list like training_id_list = ['235', '121'] now based on the id we got in that list, we need to extract the feedback. Hope this clarified : )

Comment: user2736738 sorry I forgot to replace ;;; to --- for training id. Just don't wanna make people confused

Comment: @Tech Don't change question after you get an answer. We don't have all day to help you with your problem. That being said, check the answer now. Hope it helps.