# Get information from 2 txt file together

Tags: python

I've 2 txt file feedback.txt and student.txt.
feedback.txt contains information like:

```
101---Great!!!---5.0---100114 
feedback_id---feedback---rating---training_id # I've like 1000 lines info in this txt file
```

student.txt contains information like:

```
30317998---ernst_hsieh---eh30---Ernst---https://i.jpg---EH---101
student_id---name---password---title---user_image---initials---feedback_id) # 1000 lines info in this txt file
```

Now, if I want to print out the feedback based on the student_id where do I start? Not sure how can I compile 2 txt and get information

Here's what I've tried:

```
with open ('feedback.txt') as feedback_txt: 
    read_feedback = feedback_txt.read().split('---') 
with open('student.txt') as studednt_txt: 
    read_student = student_txt.read().split('---') 
#Then I don't know
```

Comment: You need to tried read file first, line by lines, after that using the `str.split()` built-in function  to get information of one by one student

Comment: @dungxibo123 I've edited what you advised but how do I combine them

Comment: Well, you could loop over one of those lists, looking for elements in the other

Comment: Do you really need two files, though? You could just ask for a student ID and then filter the lines in the feedback file for that ID. If it doesn't exist, say no feedback for that id... If you actually want the student information, that's only when you need the second file

Comment: indeed this is what the `csv` package is all about.

Comment: This might be related from user _tech_: [find feedback from text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72132186/find-feedback-from-text-file-from-a-list-of-training-id)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest reading the files and storing them in dictionaries using the ids as keys

```py
# read feedback.txt
with open("feedback.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
    feedback = {
        feedback_id: [feedback, rating, training_id]
        for feedback_id, feedback, rating, training_id in [
            line.split("---") for line in lines if line.count("---") == 3
        ]
    }

# print(feedback)
# {'101': ['Great!!!', '5.0', '100114']}

# read student.txt
with open("student.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
    students = {
        student_id: [name, password, title, user_image, initials, feedback_id]
        for student_id, name, password, title, user_image, initials, feedback_id in [
            line.split("---") for line in lines
        ]
    }

# print(students)
# {'30317998': ['ernst_hsieh', 'eh30', 'Ernst', 'https://i.jpg', 'EH', '101']}

student_id = input("Enter your student ID: ")
# Enter your student ID: 30317998


student_feedback = feedback[students[student_id][5]]

print(f"{students[student_id][0]}'s feedback: {student_feedback[0]}")
# ernst_hsieh's feedback: Great!!!
```

Comment: EdwardI'm getting the following error when I apply your code "not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 1)". Its on where feedback = {feedbacid:[........................]}

Comment: is your feedback.txt the same as what you put in your question  (4 values on each line separated by ---)?

Comment: @ Edward I think there are some lines on my text file doesn't have 4 values separated by---. Thats the reason I was getting error. Is there any way to find out which line doesn't contain 4 values? you code works fine and I'll upvote it

Comment: I added an if into the list comp to only use lines where there are 3 ---